# Can the function $f$ be subject to the constraint $g (x,y) = 2020$ to attaint its minimum?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am given: $f, g: \mathbf{R^{2}} \to \mathbf{R} $ be differentiable functions. Fix $p \in \mathbf{R^{2}}$ such that $g(p) = 2020$. Assume that:

$$
|| \bigtriangledown f || = 1
$$

and

$$
|| \bigtriangledown g || = 1
$$

$$
 \bigtriangledown f  \cdot  \bigtriangledown g = 1/2
$$

The question is can the function $f$ subject to the constraint $g(x,y) = 2020$ to attain the mininum.

My attempt: I claim that it cannot. I apply the use the Lagrange Multiplier. So the function  $f$ subject to constraint $g(x,y) = 2020$ if $\bigtriangledown f$ is parallel to $\bigtriangledown g$.

But I use the formula of angle between $\bigtriangledown f, \bigtriangledown g$ for dot product:

$$
\theta = \cos^{-1}( \frac{ \bigtriangledown f  \cdot  \bigtriangledown g}{|| \bigtriangledown f || || \bigtriangledown g ||}  )  = \cos^{-1}(1/2)
$$
So $\bigtriangledown f$ is not parallel with $\bigtriangledown g$

Is my attempt to this problem plausible?